# Regular Expression in Finite Automata

Tags: finite-automata, automata

I need an explanation of the regular expression of :

**All strings of {a,b} which does not contain 2 or more consecutive a's.**

Comment: By explanation do you mean you want the solution of that exercise?

Comment: I do have constructed the DFA but from there I couldn't find out the Expression.

Comment: This is a question for cs, please look at the explanation of how to obtain a regular expression from your automata: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions

Comment: I think you want to think about that a must be followed by b, except at the very end.

Comment: @SoumyaKantiNaskar Did I answer your question? If so please accept if not please put a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you described should not generate a string that has "aa" as a substring.

1. If you already have a finite automata you can convert it to regex using the algorithm for state elimination: (Here is a youtube link)

[FA to regular expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-a7FKCIePdA)

2. If you want a direct regex the following would work: 
   The left part covers everything that ends with b along with the empty string. The right one covers everything that ends with a.

( (ab + b)*  +  ((ab + b)* a) )

Comment: That looks like it can be simplified to `(a?b)*a?`, i.e. `((a+ε) b)* (a+ε)`.